# Is the map $z\mapsto z^2$ a fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration

Let  $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be defined as $f(z) = z^2$.

> Is this a fibration? Or at least a Serre fibration?

I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a fibration?

Comment: Yes I do. I know basic results like fibre bundle would imply it's a Serre fibration. But here the fibre of 0 and fibre of any other points are different. So I'm guessing fibre bundle idea won't work.

Comment: it is not a Serre fibration. Consider e.g. a homotopy between the upper and the lower half of the unit circle - it cannot be lifted.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I mean how can I say it can't be lifted?

Comment: The fibers of a fibration must be homotopy equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connor's comment sums up the situation.

> Two fibres of a Hurewicz fibration over points in the same path-component of the base are homotopy equivalent.

Thus $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $z\mapsto z^2$, is not a Hurewicz fibration, since the origin has a unique preimage, whilst all other points have two.

A similar statement holds for Serre fibrations when *homotopy equivalent* is replaced by *weakly homotopy equivalent*. Thus $f$ is not even a Serre fibration.

On the other hand, by restriction we obtain $g:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, $z\mapsto z^2$, and this map is locally-trivial. Since $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is paracompact $T_2$, this map is thus a Hurewicz fibration. The fact that $g$ is locally trivial is easy to see. The easiest way to do so is to use polar coordinates to identify $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\cong S^1\times(0,\infty)$ and notice that $g$ is the product of the two-fold covering projection $S^1\rightarrow S^1$, $z\mapsto z^2$, and the homeomorphism $(0,1)\rightarrow (0,1)$, $t\mapsto t^2$.